# How to take variable from component and use it in another component or file React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

First question here so bare with me, I am having a bit of trouble trying to figure this out and would appreciate anyone's help.

So I have timer that is returned and displays with the countdown, I want to be able to call this in the index file. How would I go about having that time be called in the index file and be able to use it there to trigger other events.

I have

```
import Timer from './components/Timer';
import timer from './components/Timer';
```

and

```
console.log(timer);
```

which I have tried using just to get some output but it just displays the entire function in the console from Timer.js

Timer.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Passion+One&display=swap');
  body {
    background-color:  #7E549F;
    font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font: 50px;
  }
`;

export const Grid = styled.div`

`;

export const Row = styled.div`
display: flex;
`;

export const Col = styled.div`
flex: ${(props) => props.size};
`;


export const countdown = styled.div `
    font-size: 24pt;
`;

export default function Timer() {
    
  const [timer, setTimer] = React.useState(15);
    
  const id =React.useRef(null);
    
  const clear=()=>{
  window.clearInterval(id.current)
}
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
     id.current=window.setInterval(()=>{
      setTimer((time)=>time-1)},1000)
      
    return ()=>clear();
  },[])

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(timer===0){
        
      clear()
    }

  },[timer])


  return (
      
      <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle/>
        <div className="countdown">
            <div className = "countdown"> {timer} 
            </div>
        </div>
      
      </React.Fragment> 
  );
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What do you mean `call this`?

Comment: Do you just want to render the entire Timer component? Or do you want some other function to have access to the information of how much time is left in the timer?

Comment: Yes exactly, have access to how much time is left

Comment: being able to use {timer} like i have in the return near the bottom in other components or the index file

Comment: You have two obvious options in React.js, from my perspective: 1) create a global state, either through `context` or `Redux`, and store the timer information in there. 2) if you don't need it to be global state, what you could actually do is use custom Events -- trigger the event from your `setInterval` callback, and then listen to it wherever else you need it

Comment: I'm not sure if subtracting 1 every 1000ms is the best approach though, personally -- that's not actually guaranteed to run every second on the second, so you might consider storing a start DateTime object, and then doing the math inside a requestAnimationFrame callback or something

Comment: If you want to go for Custom Events, [this guide](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-communicate-between-independent-components-in-reactjs) would be of help learning how to use CustomEvents

Comment: Or you could make your own little object that you export from your Timer file, that allows people to register callbacks for a `timer` event firing, and call every registered function every time you update your timer. A lot of these things come with the assumption that you have only one timer on your site

Comment: Yes, we should only have the one timer. It's not so important its stays exactly in time, i just need to be able to use that time to have others events trigger. I'll try out the Custom events you mention, hopefully that's what i need. really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

If there's really only one timer, and it's a global timer, then I recommend you make a new file, `timer.js`, and it might look something like this:

```
export const timer = {
   intervalId: null,
   start: (endTime) {
      // do your setInterval here, based on the endTime
      this.endTime = endTime;
      this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
         const timerVal = ...; // calculate how many seconds are left based on the difference between now and endtime
         for (let callback of this.registeredCallbacks) {
            callback(timerVal);
         }
      },1000);
   },
   registeredCallbacks: [],
   registerCallback: callback => {
      this.registeredCallbacks.push(callback);
   }
}
```

I have'nt written all the code or done all checks required to make it production-ready, but my idea of how it should work looks something like that

That might work better as a class rather than a raw object. Up to you matey.